# webview inside react native shows only one marker from open street map?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, openstreetmap

This React Native code generates a map view using the `WebView` component to display locations marked on OpenStreetMap. It defines three locations - Paris, London, and New York City - each specified by latitude and longitude coordinates. The `generateMapURL` function calculates the bounding box for the map based on the provided locations and generates a URL with markers for each location. The markers are uniquely named to ensure each location is correctly displayed on the map. Finally, the `WebView` component renders the map using the generated URL within a React Native view.

**issue**
map only display last location ie New York location marker inside map , it does not show the rest

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default function App() {
  const location1 = { latitude: 48.8566, longitude: 2.3522 }; // Paris
  const location2 = { latitude: 51.5074, longitude: -0.1278 }; // London
  const location3 = { latitude: 40.7128, longitude: -74.0060 }; // New York City

  const generateMapURL = () => {
    const minLongitude = Math.min(location1.longitude, location2.longitude, location3.longitude);
    const maxLongitude = Math.max(location1.longitude, location2.longitude, location3.longitude);
    const minLatitude = Math.min(location1.latitude, location2.latitude, location3.latitude);
    const maxLatitude = Math.max(location1.latitude, location2.latitude, location3.latitude);

    return `https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=${minLongitude},${minLatitude},${maxLongitude},${maxLatitude}&marker=${location1.latitude},${location1.longitude}&marker=${location2.latitude},${location2.longitude}&marker=${location3.latitude},${location3.longitude}`;
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
        style={styles.map}
        source={{ uri: generateMapURL() }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
  },
});
```

Comment: The embedded OSM map has only very limited features. Use Leaflet or OpenLayers instead.